# WireMock is timing out

Tags: java, kotlin, wiremock

I am using wiremock for running my test case and it fail with timeout on http call. If I increase the time it's working fine. Below is the code I am using.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@AutoConfigureWireMock(port=0)
class BaseIT {
<<<Some common things for all calls >>>
}

class MyServiceIT : BaseIT() {
     @Test
        fun `without travel ads returns sorted organic properties`() {
            <<<< some  code >>>
            stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/myApi"))
                    .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse()
                            .withHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-protobuf")
                            .withBody(stubResponse.toByteArray())));

            val actualResponse = runBlocking {
                myService.getUserData()
            }
            
            <<< Some assertions >>
        }
}
```

I am assuming the issue is because wiremock stubs where not ready before the real call happened in the code. Is there a way to ensure wire mock stubs are ready before making the actual call ?